# Input format smpte-timecode

Tags: html, reactjs, input, timecodes

Whats the best way to set the input format when using smpte-timecode?

```
<Input 
                  placeholder="In"
                  autoFocus={true}
                  onChange={e => this.onChange(e)} 
                  type="time"
                  step="00.01" 
                  pattern="^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$"
                  style={{fontSize: "16px", width: "100%"}}/>
              )}
onChange = (element, frameRate) => {
    const { form } = this.props;
    const keys = form.getFieldValue('keys');

    keys.forEach(function (value) {
      var inTc = Timecode(form.getFieldValue('1-in'), 25); // errors
      console.log(inTc.toString());
    });
```

This keeps resulting in the following
Error: Timecode string expected as HH:MM:SS:FF or HH:MM:SS;FF

Comment: The pattern doesn't seem to match the expected string format. What does `console.log(form.getFieldValue('1-in'))` output?

Comment: what pattern restriction can i apply to an <input to make it  HH:MM:SS:FF

Comment: Something like `^\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}[:;]\d{2}$`, although I'm not very familiar with the SMTPE timecode format (does it require leading zeroes or not, can `HH` exceed 99, etc).

Comment: yes leading 0s if no hours, HH max 99